# Tradução do espanhol: «de corrido»

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução, castelhano

Tem em espanhol uma expressão adverbial, *de corrido*, que significa "sem parar, sem precisar pausa, sem duvidar" e é usada com verbos como *saber, decir, hablar* ("saber", "dizer", "falar"). Eu tenho visto traduções informais dessa expressão que consideram ela equivalente a "de cor", mais é claro que o significado exacto não é esse, mesmo que seja parcialmente válido em alguns casos. A expressão também significa, em outro contexto, simplesmente "sem parar, sem adiar". Existe uma expressão mais apropriada em português para essa ideia?

Dou alguns exemplos para exprimir melhor o que quer dizer *de corrido*:

> *El nene ya se sabe el abecedario de corrido.*
> "O menino já sabe (recitar) o alfabeto (sem fazer pausas nem duvidar)."
>
> *El presidente no sabe leer un discurso de corrido.*
> "O presidente não consigue ler um discurso (com fluência)."
>
> *Estudiamos de corrido toda la noche.*
> "A gente estudou (sem parar) a noite toda."
>
> *En el negocio atendemos de corrido de 9 a 5.*
> "Na loja temos atendimento (contínuo) das 9 às 5."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não consigo pensar numa única expressão que sirva nos teus quatro exemplos, e estou tentado a dizer que não existe tal expressão.

No primeiro exemplo diria (links ao Michaelis):

> O menino já sabe/tem o alfabeto [na ponta da língua](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/l%C3%ADngua/).
>   O menino já sabe o alfabeto [de cor e salteado](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/cor/).

Saber *de cor* significa apenas que a pessoa memorizou sem necessariamente compreender. Em particular, *falar de cor* significa proferir as palavras sem saber o que está a dizer. Mas *saber de cor e salteado* significa que sabe mesmo muito bem e responderá a qualquer pergunta sobre o assunto com grande desembaraço. Do mesmo modo, *saber/ter na ponta da língua* significa que a pessoa está prontíssima a responder adequadamente.

Nos outros exemplos tu mesmo já forneceste algumas respostas. Junto mais umas. As seguintes formas de exprimir a ideia são perfeitamente idiomáticas:

> O presidente não consegue/sabe ler um discurso [fluentemente](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/fluente/)/com [fluência](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/flu%C3%AAncia/)/[fluidez](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/fluidez/).
>   O presidente não consegue/sabe ler um discurso [desenvoltamente](http://www.aulete.com.br/desenvolto)/com [desenvoltura](http://www.aulete.com.br/desenvoltura).
>
> A gente estudou a noite toda **sem parar**.
>
> A loja está aberta **continuamente** das 9 às 5.
>   Na loja temos atendimento **contínuo** das 9 às 5.

Answer (score 4):

Eu sugiro **"ininterrupto"** (adj) ou **"ininterruptamente"** (adv)

- Estudamos a noite toda, **ininterruptamente**.
- A loja está aberta das 9 às 17, **ininterruptamente**.
- Na loja o atendimento é **ininterrupto**, de 9 às 17.
- O presidente não consegue ler um discurso sem (fazer) **interrupções**.
- O menino já sabe recitar o alfabeto **ininterruptamente**.

> **"ininterrupto"**- não interrompido, contínuo, constante. [(Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ininterrupto)

Answer (score 1):

Em adição às já mencionadas ocorre-me três expressões vagamente equivalentes, 
"*[de enfiada](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/de%20enfiada)*", "*[de empreitada](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/de%20empreitada)*" e "*[de uma assentada](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/assentada)*".

> Ele gostou tanto do livro que o leu todo de enfiada.

ou

> Comi a caixa de chocolates de uma assentada só.

ambos com o significado de feito de uma vez só, de seguida ou rapidamente.

Já a expressão "*de empreitada*" poderá ser também aplicada mas carrega uma conotação potencialmente negativa por significar também algo feito desleixadamente, com pouca qualidade ou com pouco esmero.

> A casa foi limpa de empreitada, ainda havia sujidade por todo o lado.